# Ruby Regex - Match words which begin with #

Tags: ruby, regex, match

So far I have

```
def get_hashtags(post)
  words = post.scan(/\#(\w+)/)
end
```

Which works, however it also gets words like "in#line" whereas I only want words which are beginning with #.

I have tried using \b but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: With your regexp you get exactly the words stated with #. In 'in#line' case it will capture #line. What is wrong here?

Comment: The problem is in#line doesn't start with #, it starts with 'i' so it should not be selected.

Comment: so it won't capture 'i' and this is exactly how hashtags work. '#one#two' are 2 correct hashtags. You say, it should only capture '#one' or being captured as a single hashtag?

Comment: if the sentence is "in#line hello world #hashtag #twitter" the words returned should be hashtag and twitter.

Comment: you might want to try this out: http://rubular.com/ for testing regexes!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a whitespace boundary before the #

`/(?<!\S)\#(\w+)/`